# White line between divs

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to add some css to my site i'm working on, in order to practice django. So, i bumped into some problems with two divs, more precisely with a space or white line between them.

If i type simple text, everything is ok and there's no white line. Also, i had an issue with p and other tags, but eventually figured it out and got rid of white line by setting paddings and margins to 0. But what i am supposed to do with these block content - i don't know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .sidebar{
            background-color: red;
        }

        .main-content{
            background-color: blue;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    </style>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Lists</a>
        <a href="#">Create</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, there's a white line between two divs (.sidebar and .main-content) and i have no idea why would it show up there. I also tried overflow: hidden, but it didn't quite solve the problem. It substituted the white line with padding or something i have no control over, meaning couldn't get rid of it anyways. Thank you.
[img of what im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z90uU.png)

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Lists{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
    <h1>{{mylist.title}}</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul>
            {% for content in mylist.contentbase_set.all %}
                {% if content.done == False %}
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="c{{content.id}}">{{content.content}}</li>
                {% elif content.done == True %}
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="c{{content.id}}" checked>{{content.content}}</li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <button type="submit" name="btn" value="save">Save</button>
        <input type="text" name="new_content">
        <button type="submit" name="btn" value="create">Create</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

That was the code in block content. Who would have thought, it was all about h1's margin-top.

Comment: add sample picture what you get

Comment: Done. Hopefully it helps to understand the issue better. So, this white line between red and blue is exactly what i'd love to get rid of.

Comment: can you add HTML code which renders on `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

Comment: inspect the white area with the developer tools and look at the styles to see what is causing that. You can play with the styles in the inspector to adjust things until they look right, then copy those changes into your code.

Comment: this margin property is on the `<p>` block

Comment: Thank you all guys, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue arises because some HTML has default CSS properties. For example, `p` tag default CSS is

```
display: block;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
```

To solve your problem, you can set `margin-top` to `0` for the following tag

```
p, menu, ol, hr, figure, dl, blockquote, ul, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-top: 0
}
```

Note that, all the mentioned tag default CSS property `margin-top` set to `0`

Comment: It worked, i would never guess, but h1 {margin-top: 0}, indeed, solved the issue! Thank you so much, man!

Comment: @EvgenyOcean: The best tool available for exploring and understanding these kinds of styling issues is your web browser's devtools.  [Here's a guide for how to use the "Elements" tab in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/) Similar functionality is built into every desktop web browser (even Internet Explorer).